# Adding a html/php form to drupal

Tags: forms, drupal, module

I created a load of forms using html/php then my client told me I was to use drupal. Other than re making them all is it possible to just add them to a module I create?
If so how would I go about? currently if I copy my working code into my drupal module it covers the whole page and the drupal site shows below it.

Any links? or pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be surprised how easy it is to re-create a form in the Drupal Webform module. Considering how much it gives you (user logins, XSS protection, e-mails on form submission, CSV downloads, etc.), I think it's really worth it.

I had a set of forms that used CakePHP and were a nightmare to maintain. This year we moved them to Drupal, and everyone is very happy with the new system. There are even non-techie admins who can create their own forms!

Some of the forms took only about 30 minutes to re-create in Drupal, including validation.

The only alternative I can think of is using iframes or putting your forms into node templates (one overridden template for each form), but you are still managing users, duplicate submissions, XSS attacks, data sanitization, changes to forms, and so on.

Comment: did you save to the same database? or did you save your form data to another database than the default that drupal is using? I want to save my data externally to a postDB rather than the sql that my drual is running on.

Comment: If you don't save to the same database (I'm not sure that WebForms will even let you do that), then you lose the viewing of results, CSV downloads, and other nice things. Could you download your results on a regular basis and import them into your other DB (usually easy with a CSV file)?

Comment: Hi @Graham the database has to update in real time as it is linked to a GIS system. Thanks anyways